# Overloaded Method Syntax in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm new to learning Scala.  This piece of code appears in Scala in Action.  I've got several question about it.

```
trait ReadOnly {
    val underlying: MongoDBCollection
    def name = underlying getName
    def fullName = underlying getFullName
    def find(query: Query): DBCursor = {
      def applyOptions(cursor:DBCursor, option: QueryOption): DBCursor = { 
        option match {
            case Skip(skip, next) => applyOptions(cursor.skip(skip), next)
            case Sort(sorting, next)=> applyOptions(cursor.sort(sorting), next)
            case Limit(limit, next) => applyOptions(cursor.limit(limit), next)
            case NoOption => cursor
        }
      }
      applyOptions(find(query.q), query.option)
    }
    def find(doc: DBObject): DBCursor = underlying find doc
    def findOne(doc: DBObject) = underlying findOne doc
    def findOne = underlying findOne
    def getCount(doc: DBObject) = underlying getCount doc
}
```

1) This section is talking about overloaded functions.  In it I see that `find` is overloaded.  However I've never seen a method constructed like this: `def find(doc: DBObject): DBCursor = underlying find doc`.  I've only ever seen methods defined like this: `def find(doc: DBObject): DBCursor = { ... }`.  How can find be overloaded without something in the parentheses?  What is it doing?

2) This section of the book says about the code above,

> Here you’re using pattern matching to apply each query option to the
>   result returned by the find method—in this case, DBCursor.

I know that `DBCursor` is the return type, and from an Android programming book I recently read I know that a cursor is kind of object that contains data.  What I'd like to know is which find method is this referring to, and isn't `DBCursor` simply the name of the type of object that is being returned rather than the name of the actual object?

3) The book goes on to say

> The nested applyOptions function is applied recursively because each
>   query option could wrap another query option identified by the next
>   variable, and you bail out when it matches NoOption.

I don't understand what it's talking about when it says "each query could wrap another query" for a couple of reasons.  I'm a little confused about this 'wrap' term being used, but the larger issue is how is there apparently more than one query available to wrap another query?  It's also a little ambiguous as to which `applyOptions` it's referring to.

4) How is the `match` portion of the code being implemented?  I know that you can pass in parameters to a method, but `match` is nested so how can it receive parameters to case match?

Answer (score 0):

**Scala method syntax**

You may be used to Java, where method code is always inside a pair of curly braces. But this is different in Scala where method body is just an *expression* - something that evaluates to some value (and may also have some side effects). It just so happens that in Scala, a block of code is also a valid expression and can be used as a method body.

You may ask: *Wait, if expression is something that has a value and block is an expression, then what is the value of a block?*

In Scala, a "value" of a block is the value of last expression in that block.
For example, the value of body of your `find(query: Query)` method is going to be `applyOptions(find(query.q), query.option)` - this is the "returned" value.

**DBCursor**

In MongoDB, a cursor is some kind of an iterator which you can use to lazily fetch data from database. In your example `DBCursor` is the name of type of objects returned by your `find` methods (both). I don't understand what you mean by "name of the actual object".

**QueryOption wrapping**

Read carefully - the author doesn't say that "query can wrap another query" - he says that "query *option* can wrap another query *option*". There is only one query, which may have multiple options and these options are represented using recursive structure where each option wraps another option, e.g.

```
Limit(100, Skip(200, Sort(<sorting>, NoOption)))
```

The `applyOption` function goes through that nesting structure by looking at its current option, applying appropriate operations on the cursor and proceeding to the next (wrapped) option until it finally reaches `NoOption`.

**Pattern matching**

`case Skip(skip, next)` may look like a method call, but it's not - it's just the syntax that's similar. Actually, it's quite the opposite of a method call, because here we're not *passing* some arguments somewhere but rather *taking out* some arguments out of somewhere. Each case tries to *deconstruct* our `QueryOption` against some *pattern*. For example, when we say `case Skip(skip, next) => some code`, we actually say: "when our option is a `Skip`, take the number of skipped documents out of it and call it `skip`. Also, take the next (wrapped) option out of the current option and call it `next`. Then, do something with `skip` and `next`."

Hope this brings some clarification.